# Current schema in liquibase valueComputed field

Tags: java, postgresql, liquibase

I have an  as part of a changeset. However when using valueComputed I'd like to be able to refer to the current scheme. Because at the moment I have this:

```
<update tableName="foo">
    <column name="name" valueComputed="(select b.name from bar b where baz.id = b.id)" />
</update>
```

And the issue is that the generated SQL is something like this:

```
UPDATE some_scheme.foo SET name = (select b.name from bar b where  baz.id = b.id)
```

Notie that the generated update has some_scheme attached to it, and I'd like to be able to access this in my valueComputed field. Is that possible?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using postgresql 9.4.

Comment: As far as I know, Liquibase asks the JDBC driver for the current schema. And the driver simply runs `select current_schema()`. So you should be safe using `current_schema()` inside your SQL

Comment: I think `valueComputed` has limited "recognition" features and no attribute/param replacement features. So there is no function in liquibase which could insert the schema into the SQL of `valueComputed`. So @a_horse_with_no_name suggestion of using a database function inside your SQL to retrieve the current schema might be the only solution.